# Is it a good idea to store json objects in local storage?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, local-storage, ember-cli, ember-local-storage

I've seen some sites store JSON objects in local storage. Is this practice common with ember-cli apps as well?

For example: the `currentUser` local storage key could have:

```
{"firstName": "foo", "lastName": "bar", "email": "foo@bar.com"}
```

Which can be set via `localStorage.currentUser = JSON.stringify({firstName: "foo", lastName: "bar", email: "foo@bar.com"});`

If above practice holds true. Are there any tools that facilitate manipulating data stored as JSON objects in local storage?

Is there an "Ember way" / convention I should consider?

Comment: I dont see why you would if you use ember data. If using ember-data your json is stored as models, "locally", in the store.

Comment: This means data will still need to persist on the API's end

Comment: If you want to persist data in local storage, you can still use Ember Data and use the LocalStorageAdapter: https://github.com/kurko/ember-localstorage-adapter

Comment: Its not really about wanting to store data in Ember Data. The question is whether storing JSON objects in local storage is common practice